# how to save rgb image and depth image

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to record a scene and save depth image + rgb image and point cloud data of the kinect sensor automatically into disk in jpg or png format.
I use RGBDSLAM to collect the data.And I want :

The color images are stored as 640×480 8-bit RGB images .
The depth maps are stored as 640×480 16-bit monochrome images.

But, I have no idea to do this.
Hope for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188516/how-to-save-rgb-image-and-depth-image/) by [hffgodspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/14891/hffgodspeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe the `image_saver` node that comes with [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) will let you do this. Not sure what you use rgbdslam for.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hffgodspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/14891/hffgodspeed/) on 2014-10-12**:
Thanks for your answer, could you please  tell me more detail about the usages of Image_saver node.
thanks again.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-30**:
@hffgodspeed did you read the documentation :D in case of specific questions